# What is the correct way to use a foreign key as a primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key

Here's the id generating entity:

```cs
public class ConceptDataEntry 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an example entity reliant on generated ids of the `ConceptDataEntry` entity:

```cs
public class GlobalLocationDataEntry 
{
    [Key]
    //[InverseProperty("Id")] incorrect?
    public ConceptDataEntry Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public double MapRadius { get; set; }
}
```

I am unclear on whether this is the correct way to implement this.

I'd also like to ensure each of the entity's using ids from `ConceptDataEntry` do not share id values between each other, as they're supposed to be unique both ways. I can implement that constraint manually, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `GlobalLocationDataEntry` class add an explicit foreign key property and then a navigation to the parent entity:

```cs
public class GlobalLocationDataEntry 
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ConceptDataEntry))]
    public long Id { get; set; };

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Altitude { get; set; }

    public double MapRadius { get; set; }

    public ConceptDataEntry? ConceptDataEntry { get; set; }
}
```

Here, I've used an explicit attribute to configure the foreign key, but you can also allow EF Core to discover the relationship by convention. You can find more details about this in the docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions#discovering-foreign-key-properties